# XDocument - get list of node values

Tags: silverlight, linq-to-xml

I have a XDocument something like this:

```
<LookupList>
 <ImageInfo1>
  <FieldID>1057</FieldID> 
  <FieldName>Lookup_test</FieldName> 
  <LookupText>open</LookupText> 
 </ImageInfo1>
 <ImageInfo1>
  <FieldID>1057</FieldID> 
  <FieldName>Lookup_test</FieldName> 
  <LookupText>Waiting for input</LookupText> 
 </ImageInfo1>
 <ImageInfo1>
  <FieldID>1057</FieldID> 
  <FieldName>Lookup_NEW_NAME</FieldName> 
  <LookupText>Closed</LookupText> 
 </ImageInfo1>
</LookupList>
```

I want to get

1. number and values of unique FieldName(s) and
2. a list of LookupText for each FieldName.

Can someone give me a hint how to go about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to know how to read the elements from your XDocument:

```
public void ReadXDocument(XDocument doc)
{
    foreach (XElement el in doc.Descendants("ImageInfo1"))
    {
        string fieldid = el.Element("FieldID").Value;
        string fieldName = el.Element("FieldName").Value;
        string lookupText = el.Element("LookupText").Value;
    }
```

Once you know that, using Linq to achieve your goal is relatively straight forward.

This should give you a list of distinct FieldNames:

```
    List<String> distinctNames = doc.Descendants("ImageInfo1")
                 .Select(o => o.Element("FieldName").Value)
                 .Distinct().ToList();
```

And this should give you a collection of LookupText values for each FieldName

```
    IEnumerable groups = doc.Descendants("ImageInfo1")
                 .GroupBy(o => o.Element("FieldName").Value)
                 .Select(o => new { Key = o.Key, Lookups = o.ToList() });
}
```